# Return value from Runnable Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

There are N thread and each thread sets status to 0 or 1 in its own member variable "status". In caller, if any one thread has 1 as status, overall status has to become 1.

These threads run in batch mode. So if any fails all need to be run again. 
I need to come up with some Handling for handling failure such that remaining threads also halt immediately.

The Threads are Runnable however, not Callable.

We can communicate between threads using a volatile boolean variable to signal failure. 
However, I needed to know how to read individual status from runnable threads in caller.

Comment: This sounds like a great candidate for a CompletionService. Remember to code up your runnables in such a way that they easily interrupted.

Comment: Or more simple: Observer Pattern

Comment: Take a look at [Thread Factory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) . If you use a thread pool executor you could use that interface to generate a custom Thread that extends thread but also has a method to read thread's status.

Comment: To implement status let all threads write `true` to one common `volatile boolean` (0 = false, 1 = true) because that maintains your required semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres several ways to accomplish this, I'm sure. One way is to use a completion service. Here's some (roughly tested) code:

```
public void allSucceed(final List<MyRunnable> tasks) {
    if (tasks == null || tasks.size() == 0)
        return;

    int status = 0;

    boolean success = true;
    do {
        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors
                .newFixedThreadPool(tasks.size());
        final CompletionService<MyRunnable> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<MyRunnable>(
                executorService);
        for (final MyRunnable task : tasks) {
            completionService.submit(task, task);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
            try {
                status = completionService.take().get().getStatus();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                success = false;
                break;
            }

            if (status == 0) {
                System.out.println("A task failed. All will be rerun");
                executorService.shutdownNow();
                success = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (!success);
}
```

It's critical that you design your tasks (Runnables) to be interruptible, or else any attempt to halt them will be futile.

Comment: IN my case ExectuorService is an application wide shared service and when I shut it down here, it stopped taking any further requests failing in its policy.

Comment: @fortm - is there something special about the global executor service that requires you to run these subset of threads in it? If not then I would recommend spinning off a separate service (as I have shown) to execute the tasks in.

Comment: @fortm - But if you ***have*** to use the global executor, then the code will need to be refactored. You will need to store the futures that you get from `completionService.submit` in a list, then instead of `executorService.shutdownNow`, you would iterate through the list of futures and call `cancel` on each one.

Comment: Yeah by design I hav to use the global one.. CAlling cancel on individual thread Future would require handling InterruptedException in Threads. I right now tried adding a volatile boolean , but that did not succeed as ExectuorService in my case really works on GenericObjectPool Objects, each of which are created doing "new" .So, changing a member variable for one did not reflect in other.

Comment: @fortm - gotcha. Quick point, your tasks/threads should be designed to be interruptible. This is the only way to ensure that you can actually stop them on demand. So, having to handle the interrupted exception inside them, is actually a good thing.

Comment: What I mean is when GEnericObjectPool borrowObject is called, then a new object is returned by pool in overriden implementation for makeObject method.

Comment: Since each of my Thread is basically a series of method calls to be executed only once , each call taking itsestimated  time. I will add throws Exception declaration to each method and in run() catch(InterruptedException) and return from there ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24985/discussion-between-perception-and-fortm)

Comment: If each task is a big object,can this call be expensive ? completionService.submit(task, task); I have submit done from one thread and polling done from other where I get task object and then its status code

Answer (score 1):

You can simply ask the threads set a value in the caller's thread:

Field in caller:

```
int[] status = new int[NUM_THREADS];
```

Then give an index to each Runnable so it can set its status in the array, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
    final index = i;

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        void run() {
            // have your code stop occasionally to check for any failures
            if (>I failed>)
                status[index] = 1;
        }
    }
    // start thread using Runnable
}
```

To detect halting, have your Runnables occasionally check for any failures in the arraym or you could have add separate `boolean` flag to your caller class:

```
volatile boolean failed = false;
Object lock = new Object();
```

then in your runnables:

```
if (<I failed>) {
    synchronised (lock) {
        failed = true;
    }
}
```

and your check for failure during the work would be:

```
synchronised (lock) {
    if (failed) {
        // clean up resources
        status[index] = -1; // consider using a separate value for "halted"
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, how do you handle the case of waiting on completion of all threads, but interrupting remaining threads after the first failure is recorded?

Comment: volatile is not doing what you think it is doing there.

Comment: @Perception How about now?

Comment: @Bohemian - are you proposing the caller do a 'busy loop' through the status array, then halt all tasks immediately it encounters a failure status?

Comment: @Perception If adding to this code I would use a `CountDownLatch`, but I was trying to isolate the issues asked. Something like your answer is what *I* would do.